# Is ag-grid responsive like DataTables from datatables.net?

Tags: angular, datatables, ag-grid

In **ag-grid** is it possible for invisible columns on smaller screens to automatically get collapsed into a **plus** button at the beginning of the row and then revealed as a stack of rows when the user presses this button?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in Ag-grid to show/hide columns.

When you want to set one or several columns to be invisible, just call:

```
gridColumnApi.setColumnVisible('columnName', false);
```

And, set true, when you want to show again.

Comment: Thank you. My question was if the grid will hide or show columns automatically as the viewport size changes.

Comment: it is not providing hide/show automatically but you can give automatically a width size according to you device width. Normally you must give width and height size for container of ag-grid tag. When gridReady func is called, you can reach device width. So you can show or hide column based on this information. To do make this easy, provide a function and call inside onGridReady func is called.

Comment: Thank you very much.